# Using a list for BigInteger addition

Tags: java, arraylist, byte, biginteger

I am implementing my own BigInteger class using an ArrayList and am unsure how to write my addition method.

```
public BigInt plus(BigInt operand){
    //deep copy?
    ArrayList<Byte> a = this.digit;
    ArrayList<Byte> b = operand.digit;
    ArrayList<Byte> sum = new ArrayList<>();

    //code  

    return new BigInt();
}
```

The goal is to pass in another BigInt, take its Arraylist of bytes and add it to the Arraylist of bytes of the current BigInt, but when doing this, if the value of adding 2 bytes together you would carry the '1' and add it to the next byte in the list.

IE:

```
BigInt1 = "3,2,1,7"

BigInt2 = "1,4,3,5"
```

Adding 7 and 5 would create 12, so the 1 is carried and 2 will be in that index for the returned BigInt.

The final BigInt should be

```
BigIntSum = "4,6,5,2"
```

My question is, how can I iterate through these lists, add the bytes and carry a number if necessary, and add that? Any help is greatly appreciated. BigInt has a constructor that can take a string that is turned into its own ArrayList

Comment: Why? The addition of two integers produces another integer. You don't need a list. You don't even appear to heed this method.

Comment: I'm using bytes, and a byte can not be a 2 digit number. The BigInt class places each digit of the number into a list of bytes. This class is meant to take numbers larger than a normal integer can handle, hence using the list.

Comment: Actually, a byte *can* be a 2-digit number, although I fail to see how that would get around needing a list (assuming, as in your example, you need to represent numbers with more than 2 digits).

Answer (score 0):

something like this...

```
carry = 0
for i = bigInt1.Length - 1 to zero
 sum = bigInt1[i] + bigInt2[i] + carry
 if (sum > 10) {
    sum = sum mod 10
    carry = 1
 else
    carry = 0
 endif
 bigIntResult = sum
loop i
// after the loop, if carry == 1, then you have overflow and you need to lengthen bigIntResult
```

Comment: BigIntResult does not appear to be a BigInt, and only ever has the value of a single digit of the sum.

Comment: @ScottHunter It doesn't compute any answer. The symbols are not declared, there's no class container, no package, no method container, and no delimiters. I think it's obvious that bigIntResult is a BigInt type but if you are confused I assume that voting it down made you feel better.

Comment: I was talking about the logic: it assigns `bigIntResult` to be the last *digit* computed (which makes it far from obvious what type it is), so even if faithfully translated to executable code, would not work properly.

Comment: @ScottHunter As I wrote earlier, I think it's obvious that bigIntResult is a BigInt type.

Comment: Whatever type it is, it has the wrong value, as I've now said for the 4th time.

Comment: @ScottHunter I'm happy to go round-and-round with you: Your basic premise is incorrect because I provided p-code, not a working program. Expecting the coder to recognize bigIntResult as a BigInt object and code it appropriately is reasonable in this situation. Have a nice day!